# How to configure the fetch() URL depending on the environment in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, fetch-api

I have a Visual Studio 2019 Solution containing 2 projects:

1. An ASP.NET Core Web App (Razor Pages) project
2. An ASP.NET Core Web API project

I am using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to make JavaScript calls to the Web API from Razor Pages in the Razor Pages application.

For example:

```
fetch("https://localhost:44325/api/Customer/12")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => processData(data))
    .catch(err => showError(err));
```

How do I configure the url (the first parameter to the fetch() call above) depending on the environment that the Web App is running please - i.e. development (as above), staging, production etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I configure the url (the first parameter to the fetch() call
> above) depending on the environment that the Web App is running please
>
> - i.e. development (as above), staging, production etc?

First, based on the environments to add multiple appsettings.Environment.json : For example, the appsettings.Production.json and appsettings.Development.json files:

appsettings.Production.json:

```
{
  "API": {
    "URL": "https://localhost:44325/api/Customer/12", //store the url
    "Environment": "Production"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

Then, in the View Page, use the `@inject` directive to add the `IConfiguration`, then you could access the configuration value from the view page. And then you can use a hidden field to store the Api URL, before using the Tetch Api, use the Jquery to find the hidden field and get the URL.

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnv

@inject Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration configuration
 
<p> ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = @hostingEnv.EnvironmentName</p>
 
<p> ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = @configuration["API:Environment"]</p>
<p> API URl : <span>@configuration["API:URL"]</span></p>

<input type="hidden" id="hid_apiurl" value="@configuration["API:URL"]" />
```

The result as below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for something similar and I found this article.
https://www.thecodebuzz.com/set-appsettings-json-dynamically-dev-and-release-environments-asp-net-core/

You can have multiple types of appsettings.json files with configuration details that are specific to DEV, TEST Or STAGING, and PROD.
Then just define your url in the setting file such as

appsettings.Development.json

```
{    
  "ApiUrls": {
    "CustomerApi": "https://localhost:44325/api/Customer/12",
  }
}
```

appsettings.prod.json

```
  {    
      "ApiUrls": {
        "CustomerApi": "https://productionurlblablabla/api/Customer/12",
      }
    }
```

etc. It is all described there it worked for me but I am not an author of that so feel free to read and good luck with that.

Comment: Thanks @Vladimir - are you able to provide a code snippet of how you access these settings from within the JavaScript code please?

Comment: I was calling my api on the back-end site but I am pretty sure you can store that value in the variable and pass it in your view. I am using mvc but I am pretty sure in razor pages you have something like  ViewData["MyApiUrl"] = _configuration.GetValue<string>("ApiUrls:CustomerApi")  and after that you can just use string interpolation or something like that to inject it into your fetch script

Comment: where _configuration is private readonly IConfiguration

Comment: also you can call you api on the back-end side, it is more secure than just render whatever you want in the view